# not losing the focus event on jquery

Tags: jquery, focus, live, blur

I have this html:

```
<div style="display:none" id="myDiv">
 <a href="javascript:adToText('some text 1')">click me</a><br>
 <a href="javascript:adToText('some text 2')">click me</a><br>
 <a href="javascript:adToText('some text 3')">click me</a><br>
</div>

<textarea id="myText">
 hey
</textarea>

javascript:
$("textarea").live("focus",function(){
 $("#myDiv").css("display","block");
});

$("textarea").live("blur",function(){
 $("#myDiv").css("display","none");
});
```

on `textarea` `focus` I set the `div` style to `display:block` so we can `click` the javascript link
the script will add text to the `textarea`

on `textarea` `blur` I set the div style to `display:none`

I need to see the `div` links so I can add them more then 1 time
but what happens is that when I `click` a link the div sets to `display:none` because I am `focusedout` of the `textarea`

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent loosing focus like this:

```
$('a').mousedown(function() { return false; })
      .click(function() { alert('works'); });
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/2qMFX/7/

Comment: did not help i still loos the focus and the div disepeers

Comment: Probably you have some logic whitch moves focus outside of textarea, because I've checked sample in couple browsers and it works. I've updated it with text appending to the text area.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you let user close the `div` **on-demand**. This means that on entering focus to the `<textarea>`, you display `div`, and on `div` you have a close button, that use can click and close.